# Spring Boot with Oracle Database Connection Taking Too Long

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot App that connects to an oracle database. The connection takes place whenever I start the app up:

`Started KanbanApplication in 8.487 seconds (JVM running for 11.153)`

Not bad... I can live with that long of a startup. But when I want to connect to a different Oracle User that I have, the startup time drastically increases:

`Started KanbanApplication in 67.124 seconds (JVM running for 68.904)`

The part where the loading takes the longest is in between these two areas of loading:

`HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`

*About a minute passes, then it finally finishes loading:*

```
HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Started KanbanApplication in 67.124 seconds (JVM running for 68.904)
```

I wish that I could give you more details about the composition of the user connections, but in my opinion the two schemas are exactly the same. Same tables, basically no data in them, etc. How can I increase the speed at which my Spring Boot Application connects to the Oracle Database User? I simply cannot wait over a minute every time that I need to recompile my application.

Comment: Ask your DBA to trace your session

Answer (score 0):

I guess that other user just has access to way too many objects. Many of the JDBC metadata implementations in the Oracle driver take quite some time for certain unrestricted users because all system schemas are returned. I would suggest you restrict that user to only see application related objects to speed this up. Apart from that, you could also try to disable the schema validation by setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user using session creation privileges.

```
CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED BY welcome1; 
ALTER USER hr DEFAULT TABLESPACE users QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users;  
ALTER USER hr TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;  
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE VIEW, ALTER SESSION, CREATE SEQUENCE TO hr;  
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE DATABASE LINK, RESOURCE, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr;
```

**Refer to this link for creating the user:
I was able to resolve the issue.**

https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/cloud/load-db-container-sql-developer.html